Как делать набор совокупностей с <=> посередине
Возьмём пример:

В лучшей попытке получилось так:
|x + 7| = 9\\

\begin{cases}
x + 7 = -9\\
\iff
\begin{cases}
x = -9 -7\\
\iff
\begin{cases}
x = -16\\
x = +2
\end{cases}\\
x = +9 -7
\end{cases}\\
x + 7 = +9
\end{cases}

Результат следующий:

Как можно сделать так, чтобы эти формулы отоброжались как на первой картинке?

Вместо {cases} используйте {array} и в нем квадратные скобки:
\begin{array}{l}
    |x + 7| = 9 \\[.5em]
    \left [
    \begin{array}{l}
        x + 7 = -9 \\
        x + 7 = +9
    \end{array}
    \right. \iff  \left [
    \begin{array}{l}
        x = -9 - 7 \\
        x = +9 - 7
    \end{array}
    \right. \iff \left [
    \begin{array}{l}
        x = -16 \\
        x = +2
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{array}


Результат:


Объяснение:
Синтаксис требует записывать скобки всегда в парах, но вас интересует только левая (квадратная) скобка. Правую должно пропустить, потому я вместо пары [, ] применил пару \left [, \right.
(\right. значит, что правая скобка будет пропущена, но правильный синтаксис сохранен).
